# Setup a Centos 6 server as the php server

Tags: php, linux

I'm new to PHP and currently working with XAMPP and Eclipse on Windows 7.
I have another computer which runs Centos 6 and have the latest Apache and Mysql versions.
I want to use that computer to run my PHP files instead of XMAPP.
I'll will appreciate a simple explanation, as i said before i new to this.

Thanks

Comment: Into which concrete problem did you run? Normally you just place the PHP files there, change the db configuration of your script and open it up in the webbrowser.

Comment: First you'd have to actually ask a question, and server setup is off-topic for this site anyways.

Comment: @MarcB: As long as it's development related, it's ok to ask setup questions.

Comment: recomend howtoforge.com there is huge amount of tutorials

Comment: Thanks to the helpers I already installed PHP in my server, and uploaded the database to PhpMyAdmin.
The thing is, i want to continue develop on my Windows computer with eclipse PDT, meaning i have to define the Eclipse workspace to the server, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache and CentOS, you can just install the PHP packages. yum install php

You'll want an FTP also, do go with yum install vsftpd

Then you'll need to configure the user accounts on it.

Answer (score 0):

`yum install httpd phpmyadmin mysql` will install everything you need for the server.
Copy paste the files in your `C:\xampp\htdocs` to `/var/www/`. Export your Database and Users from the Windows database and dump it into the one on CentOS using `phpmyadmin`. And you should be good to go.